# Django - Common data, few views

Tags: django

I need your help because I have approximately 6 views having common data.

Example similar to my problem :

```
def informationPlayers(request,nameTeam):

    try :
        team = Team.objects.get(name = nameTeam)    
    except Team.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect(teams)


    if not request.user.is_authenticated():         
        formLogin   = loginForm(auto_id=False)
        countMembers = team.members.count()
    else :      
        members    = team.members.members()

    ... code specific to this view ...


def informationCoach(request,nameTeam):

    try :
        team = Team.objects.get(name = nameTeam)    
    except Team.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect(teams)


    if not request.user.is_authenticated():         
        formLogin   = loginForm(auto_id=False)
        countMembers = team.members.count()
    else :      
        members    = team.members.members()

    ... code specific to this view ...
```

So these 2 views have same variables and an algorithm (if user is authenticated or not).

I don't want to write this algortihm and variables in all views using them, How can I do please ?

*I already try TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS but it's applied in all views/pages of my site, I don't want that.*

Comment: if you have common functions for some views then i would suggest using decorators

Comment: Switch to class views and have all these classes derived from the same class. Otherwise, simply put the common code on a function and call it from each of these views. This is just Python.

Comment: @dkarchmer, your method works with Django ?? How can I passe the argument "nameTeam" to the class ? :o ArpitSolanki, I will see that !

Comment: Class based Views is the modern way to implement views, exactly because Python classes are much more powerful for sharing code. I will can write an answer if you are ok with classes

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: I will try to use class based views ("class ...(View):"). I am ok for the answer by you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @dkarchmer, I did something like that  :

*version modified :*

```
class ProjetMixin(object) :

    project = None
    coms = None
    form = None

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs) :

        context = super(ProjetMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        try :
            self.project = Project.objects.get(name = self.kwargs['name']) #in urls 

        except Project.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect(projects)

        self.coms = self.project.coms_set.order_by('-date_send')

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():        
            self.form = formForm(auto_id=False)         

        context['project'] = self.project
        context['coms'] = self.coms
        context['form'] = self.form

        return context


class FicheProjetView(ProjetMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/homeProject.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(FicheProjetView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST :
            ...                                 

    return context

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FicheProjetView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

It's proper ?

Comment: I cannot tell if it works without testing it myself, but I won't do that, so if it works for you, it is good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer using class base views. Classes in Python (and any other language that supports them) is a good way to share code while making it obvious to any other developer which views should and should not share this code.

Your `urls.py` should be kept about the same, except that you will need to call the class methods. Something like:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<nameTeam>[^/]+)/player/$', PlayerView.as_view(), name='player_view'),
    url(r'^(?P<nameTeam>[^/]+)/coach/$', CoachView.as_view(), name='player_view'),
]
```

and then on your `views.py`, you would do something like:

```
class TeamAccessMixin(object):
    # This is really just a regular Python object
    team = None
    formLogin = None
    countMembers = None
    members = None

    def get_team(self, teamName):
      try :
        self.team = Team.objects.get(name = nameTeam)    
      except Team.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect(self.teams)

      if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():         
        self.formLogin = loginForm(auto_id=False)
        self.countMembers = team.members.count()
      else :      
        self.members = team.members.members()

class PlayerView(TeamAccessMixin, DetailView):
    model = Player
    template_name = 'team/player.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlayerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.get_team(kwargs['teamName']);
        context['team'] = self.team
        context['members'] = self.members
        # Special code to add additional context specific to this view
        ...
        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PlayerView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class CoachView(TeamAccessMixin, DetailView):
    model = Coach
    template_name = 'team/coach.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CoachView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.get_team(kwargs['teamName']);
        context['team'] = self.team
        context['members'] = self.members
        # Special code to add additional context specific to this view
        ...
        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CoachView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Just answering your specific question, but I also see you may not understand other aspects of Django (like login decorators, which will ensure you users are logged in or will automatically redirect them). So, as an added bonus, here is how I would have implemented what you are trying to do (assuming some details you are not specifying):

```
class TeamAccessMixin(object):
    # This is really just a regular Python object

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      # It is best practice to simply give a 404 if the record does not exist
      object = get_object_or_404(Team, slug=self.kwargs['nameTeam'])
      return object

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # the decorator will ensure all users are logged in or will redirect to login page
        return super(TeamAccessMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class PlayerView(TeamAccessMixin, DetailView):
    model = Player
    template_name = 'team/player.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlayerView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['team'] = self.object
        context['members'] = self.object.members
        # Special code to add additional context specific to this view
        ...
        return context

class CoachView(TeamAccessMixin, DetailView):
    model = Player
    template_name = 'team/coach.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CoachView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['team'] = self.object
        context['members'] = self.object.members
        # Special code to add additional context specific to this view
        ...
        return context
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! :) I will try to implement this in my code, and I will say you if it's works ;)

Comment: I have a question : Where are you using get_team ?